# Ms Access - Inserting character into a string - with different characters length

Tags: ms-access, insert, character

I have the following field in my Ms Access table **tblCode**:

```
      Code
      A00
      A000
      A0102
      Z688594
```

6 000+ records

I am trying to insert "." character, after the 3rd character in that field, so the updated result should be:

```
     Code      Code1
     A00       A00
     A000      A00.0
     A0102     A01.02
     Z688594   Z68.8594
```

My code for that field, in a "Design" MsAccess view is:

```
     Code1: IIf(Len([Code])<=3,[Code],Left([Code],3) & "." & Right([Code],1))
```

But I know that my very last expression is wrong and would only work if I'd have the same number of characters thru this table.

I am having result as

```
       Code1
       A00
       A00.0
       A01.2
       Z68.4
```

Please, help me adjust the RIGHT side of my result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `Right`/`Len` to add the characters after the ".", it is probably better to just use `Mid`:

```
SELECT Code, 
    IIf(Len([Code])<=3,[Code],Left([Code],3) & "." & Mid([Code],4)) AS ConvertedCode
FROM tblCode;
```

Regards,

Comment: Oh, you're correct !!!
I didn't think about mid because I thought it would require the 1st and the last position for extraction  Misunderstood how it works

Answer (score 1):

We can try using a combination of `LEN` and concatenation here:

```
SELECT
    [Code],
    IIF(LEN([Code]) <= 3, [Code],
        LEFT([Code], 3) & "." & RIGHT([Code], LEN([Code]) - 3)) AS Code1
FROM yourTable;
```

The only change in my logic over what you already have is that the length passed in to `RIGHT()` now is dynamic, and uses the remaining number of characters in the code (offset by the 3 already used on the left side of the dot).